# Display images in a listview based on file type android

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a file manager for android and I'm displaying the files/folders in a list view. At this point I'd like to display an icon for folders and a different one for files. I'm trying to differentiate between the two using the File methods isDirectory() and isFile() but they only come up as files.. Unless I navigate to the root directory in which case it works fine. Not sure where I've gone wrong, here is the code:

```
public class DisplayDirectoryActivity extends Activity {

List<Map<String, String>> currentFileList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
String path;
String query;

ListView lv;
SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_directory_activity);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Receive current directory path
    String currentPath = (String) getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("currentPath");
    path = currentPath;

    // Add all directories on card to List->Map for display in listview
    populateFiles();

    // Create ListView attached to ListView in xml definition
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Create a new adapter with the files needed to be listed
    simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), currentFileList,
            R.layout.list_view_adapter, new String[] { "file", "img" },
            new int[] { R.id.file, R.id.img });
    // Set the new adapter to the ListView
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

        @Override

public void populateFiles() {
    // Clear list for updating
    currentFileList.clear();
    // Create a file from the current path
    File current = new File(this.path);
    // Array of the files within the current directory
    String[] subFiles = current.list();

    // Add each file in the current directory to currentFileList
    for (int i = 0; i < subFiles.length; i++) {
            currentFileList.add(createEntry("file", subFiles[i]));
    }
}

// Create a map of key to filename for adding to the currentFileList
private HashMap<String, String> createEntry(String type, String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> entry = new HashMap<String, String>();
    File current = new File(name);
    //If the current file is a directory, display icon as folder
    if (current.isDirectory()) {
        entry.put(type, name);
        entry.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.folder));
    }
    //If the current file is not a directory, display icon as a file
    else {
        entry.put(type, name);
        entry.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.file));
    }

    return entry;

}
```

EDIT: File in createEntry() was constructed with the wrong arguments, problem fixed.

Comment: Please make your question more clear... what do you mean by _"they only come up as files"_ and by _"Unless I navigate to the root directory in which case it works fine_"?

Comment: I meant I wanted them to come with a folder icon if it the file is a directory and a file icon if the file is a file, but all items in the list would appear as files even if they were folders. I fixed the problem anyhow, the file constructed in createEntry() had the wrong arguments.